# Email id not getting from facebook in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, email

```
[SCFacebook getUserFields:@"id, name, email,gender ,birthday, about, picture.type(large)" callBack:^(BOOL success, id result) {
                NSLog(@"success or not:%d",success);
                if (success) {
                  NSString *username = [result valueForKey:@"id"];
                  NSString *email=[result valueForKey:@"email"];
                  NSLog(@"email:%@",email);
                  }
                 else{ 
                   NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                 }
               }];
```

In my project have **facebook login, share post** on facebook so i am integrate **SCFacebook** demo in my project but in some  **facebook  account email id is not getting.** 
So, any one can please resolved my problem??

Comment: I think SCFacebook uses old facebook graph api and SDK. try to do it via Facebook 4.2 SDK

Comment: then how can we know SCFacebook which version uses for graph api and sdk?

Comment: We can know by github, this project is updated 10 month ago. Facebook release 4.x sdk before 2 or 3 months. So, I hope this will be old sdk. If you want to login through fb sdk 4.x sdk. I will help you by providing an answer.

Comment: In readme they given : The SCFacebook 3.0 is a simple and cleaner to use the api Facebook-ios-sdk with Blocks.

Facebook SDK 3.18 for iOS

Comment: yes i check it. but still it is not working..   u have any other solution?

Comment: Users can deny the permission, or they might not even have an email address on file with Facebook (f.e. if they registered using their mobile), or it might not be verified. In all those cases you will not get an email address – so don’t _rely_ on it in your app. If your app _needs_ an email address for the user, then provide them with a field where they can manually enter it if necessary.